# What fonts were used to type the followingquestion paper in MS Word?

Tags: latex, microsoft-word-2016

What fonts were used to type the followingquestion paper in MS Word?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  That's an italicized serif font, but there are dozens of very similar ones.  You would need to compare them, and decide which of the ones available to you are close enough for your purpose.  Unfortunately, questions that ask to identify something from an image aren't really a good fit for the site because there isn't a practical way for future readers to search for it if they have a similar question (which is kind of the purpose of the site).  So the question is likely to be closed, but maybe you'll get some useful advice before then.

Answer (score 1):

MS Word Equation Editor is probably your best bet.

Just type "Equation" at the top bar "Tell me what you want to do" and you will get the Equation Editor.

When I put the Equation - it comes up as Cambria Math..

Comment: I did that but the fonts are not matching. Is it something of a latex issue?